# animate to light yellow then back to white? jQUery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to make my ul li's background color to turn yellow then back to white . i use the code below but it's not working.

```
$('#items ul li.test').animate({ 'background-color' : '#FFFEBC' },  3000, function(){
  $('#items ul li.test').animate({ 'background-color' : '#ffffff' }, 3000);
});
```

I have included jQuery library of course , and this code is triggered by another function. the function works but not the animate.

`.test` is the `ul li` class.

Is there any problem with the code??

Comment: -1: Insufficient research. It tells you what is wrong in the second paragraph of the manual for this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery on its own doesn't support animating colors; see the [`animate` docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

jQuery UI [adds the ability](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/) to animate colors to it. If you're not using it for anything else, though, it's a big hammer. :-)

There are a couple of other plug-ins that add color animation, such as [this one](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/); if you do a search you should find several options to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but **background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used**). Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be specified where applicable.

So use the plugin it tells you to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery UI and the highlight method to aceive this effect.

Once you have jquery UI,

Simply use the highlight effect

```
$('#items ul li.test').effect('highlight');
```

You can download **only** the highlight effect if you want from the jquery UI download builder

Answer (score 0):

Well, It doesn't seem any error in your code.. But you might have set CSS class for ID (#items); that might override your background-color.

For your help, I have just remove ID and Class from HTML, and It's working fine !! See Below...

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>123</li>
     <li>456</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery Code**   ( I have used (Document).ready() - in your case you're handling on event.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('ul li').animate({ 'background-color' : '#FFFEBC' },  500, 
         function(){ $('ul li').animate({ 'background-color' : '#CCCCCC' }, 500,
         function(){ $('ul li').animate({ 'background-color' : '#ffffff' }, 500);
       });
   });}
);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

try this code

$('#items ul li.test').animate({ 'backgroundColor' : '#FFFEBC' },  3000, function(){
  $('#items ul li.test').animate({ 'backgroundColor' : '#ffffff' }, 3000);
});

i had not tested it, but it may work.